# Determine which function to call based on length of decimal

Tags: c#, floating-point, decimal

In C#, I have a situation where I have two possible numbers in a textbox control.

The numbers can be either:

a) .xxxx

or

b) .xx

How do I write a condition that says, "If the textbox has 4 decimal places, then call this function, otherwise, if the textbox has 2 decimal places, then call this function."

Seems easy, but I don't know how to evaluate the decimal places.

Thanks much!

Comment: If user enters ".1200", do you want to count that as 4 decimal places or 2?

Comment: Are 0s significant?  i.e. is "3.4200" considered a 2- or 4-place number?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... sorry I wasn't clear. Yes, if a user enter 1.4000 then it's 4 decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex

```
new Regex(@"\.\d{2}$").IsMatch(input.Value)
```

Comment: This regex will match two *or more* decimal places, so doesn't answer the question. You should use the `$` end-of-line anchor if you want to match *exactly* two decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(txtNumber.Text.Split(new[]{'.'})[1].Length == 2)
{
    //case b
}
else
{
    //case a
}
```

you may want to take the decimal separator from the system's current culture instead of hardcoding the dot.

Answer (score 2):

You could take advantage of a very obscure feature of the Decimal type.  Its internal representation is a 96-bit number with an exponent.  The exponent is equal to the number of digits in the fraction, even if the fractional digits are zero.  Thus:

```
public static int GetFractionalDigits(string txt) {
  decimal value = decimal.Parse(txt);
  return (decimal.GetBits(value)[3] >> 16) & 0x7fff;
}
```

Use decimal.TryParse() if you need to validate the user input.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Condition will evaluate `true` on two but not four decimal places:</s>

```
Math.Round( 100*x ) == 100*x
```

**EDIT:** above condition works only for Decimal type. Well, following works for real numbers of all types:

```
( Math.Ceiling( 100 * x ) - 100 * x ) < 10e-8 )
```

**EDIT:** Well, if you are interested in strings then use following (extension string contains last point and subsequent digits/numbers):

```
System.IO.Path.GetExtension( input ).Length
```

Comment: This works if the OP is expecting a Decimal type. However, with a float, it doesn't. So, as long as OP checks it as a decimal, it should be fine.

Comment: So what happens if the user enters 1.0000

Comment: See my comment above in the original post. What about doing something with String.Format?

Answer (score 1):

This may not work perfectly depending on your needs, but it works for my purposes and could be useful to someone else.

```
static class MathCustom
{
    static public byte NumberOfDecimals(decimal value)
    {
        sbyte places = -1;
        decimal testValue;

        do
        {
            places++;
            testValue = Math.Round(value, places);
        } while (testValue != value);

        return (byte)places;
    }

    static public byte NumberOfDecimals(float value)
    {
        sbyte places = -1;
        float testValue;

        do
        {
            places++;
            testValue = (float)Math.Round((decimal)value, places);
        } while (testValue != value);

        return (byte)places;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This version of NumberOfDecimals allows you to provide a Maximum
    /// for allowable decimals. This method will allow for the correction
    /// of floating point errors when it is less than 10 or passed in as null.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value to check the number of held decimal places</param>
    /// <param name="knownMaximum"></param>
    /// <returns>The number of decimal places in Value.</returns>
    static public byte NumberOfDecimals(decimal value, byte? knownMaximum)
    {
        byte maximum;
        decimal localValue;
        sbyte places = -1;
        decimal testValue;

        if (knownMaximum == null)
        {
            maximum = 9;
        }
        else
        {
            maximum = (byte)knownMaximum;
        }

        localValue = Math.Round(value, maximum);

        do
        {
            places++;
            testValue = Math.Round(localValue, places);
        } while (testValue != localValue);

        return (byte)places;
    }

}
```