# Is there a way to get the "significant figures" of a decimal?

Tags: .net, decimal, precision, significant-digits

## Update

OK, after some investigation, and thanks in big part to the helpful answers provided by Jon and Hans, this is what I was able to put together. So far I think it seems to work well. I wouldn't bet my life on its total correctness, of course.

```
public static int GetSignificantDigitCount(this decimal value)
{
    /* So, the decimal type is basically represented as a fraction of two
     * integers: a numerator that can be anything, and a denominator that is 
     * some power of 10.
     * 
     * For example, the following numbers are represented by
     * the corresponding fractions:
     * 
     * VALUE    NUMERATOR   DENOMINATOR
     * 1        1           1
     * 1.0      10          10
     * 1.012    1012        1000
     * 0.04     4           100
     * 12.01    1201        100
     * 
     * So basically, if the magnitude is greater than or equal to one,
     * the number of digits is the number of digits in the numerator.
     * If it's less than one, the number of digits is the number of digits
     * in the denominator.
     */

    int[] bits = decimal.GetBits(value);

    if (value >= 1M || value <= -1M)
    {
        int highPart = bits[2];
        int middlePart = bits[1];
        int lowPart = bits[0];

        decimal num = new decimal(lowPart, middlePart, highPart, false, 0);

        int exponent = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10((double)num));

        return exponent;
    }
    else
    {
        int scalePart = bits[3];

        // Accoring to MSDN, the exponent is represented by
        // bits 16-23 (the 2nd word):
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx
        int exponent = (scalePart & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;

        return exponent + 1;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it all that thoroughly. Here are a few sample inputs/outputs, though:

```
Value          Precision
0              1 digit(s).
0.000          4 digit(s).
1.23           3 digit(s).
12.324         5 digit(s).
1.2300         5 digit(s).
-5             1 digit(s).
-5.01          3 digit(s).
-0.012         4 digit(s).
-0.100         4 digit(s).
0.0            2 digit(s).
10443.31       7 digit(s).
-130.340       6 digit(s).
-80.8000       6 digit(s).
```

Using this code, I imagine I would accomplish my goal by doing something like this:

```
public static decimal DivideUsingLesserPrecision(decimal x, decimal y)
{
    int xDigitCount = x.GetSignificantDigitCount();
    int yDigitCount = y.GetSignificantDigitCount();

    int lesserPrecision = System.Math.Min(xDigitCount, yDigitCount);

    return System.Math.Round(x / y, lesserPrecision);
}
```

I haven't really finished working through this, though. Anybody who wants to share thoughts: that would be much appreciated!

---

## Original Question

Suppose I have write this code:

```
decimal a = 1.23M;
decimal b = 1.23000M;

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

The above will output:

```
1.23
1.23000
```

I find that this also works if I use `decimal.Parse("1.23")` for `a` and `decimal.Parse("1.23000")` for `b` (which means this question applies to cases where the program receives user input).

So clearly a `decimal` value is somehow "aware" of what I'll call its *precision*. However, I see no members on the `decimal` type that provide any way of accessing this, aside from `ToString` itself.

Suppose I wanted to multiply two `decimal` values and trim the result to the precision of the less precise argument. In other words:

```
decimal a = 123.4M;
decimal b = 5.6789M;

decimal x = a / b;

Console.WriteLine(x);
```

The above outputs:

```
21.729560302171195125816619416
```

What I'm asking is: how could I write a method that would return `21.73` instead (since `123.4M` has four significant figures)?

To be clear: I realize I could call `ToString` on both arguments, count the significant figures in each string, and use this number to round the result of the calculation. I'm looking for a *different* way, if possible.

(I *also* realize that in most scenarios where you're dealing with significant figures, you probably don't need to be using the `decimal` type. But I'm asking because, as I mentioned in the beginning, the `decimal` type *appears* to include information about precision, whereas `double` does not, as far as I know.)

Comment: I didn't know I wanted to know this until you asked it +1!

Comment: Your function does not work correctly for some of those inputs. For example, -0.012 is only 2 significant digits - not 4.

Comment: @JamesJones Clearly he is referring to a different concept of significant digits, not that one would learn in a math course. Maybe the name "used digits" would make more sense.

Comment: For getting the number of decimal places see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70401738/450913).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Decimal.GetBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx) to get the raw data, and work it out from that.

Unfortunately I don't have time to write sample code at the moment - and you'll probably want to use [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) for some of the manipulation, if you're using .NET 4 - but hopefully this will get you going. Just working out the precision and then calling `Math.Round` on the original result may well be a good start.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer even though I haven't finished working out my solution, because it definitely gives me the information I need. (Sadly, I was hoping for something a bit more accessible than `GetBits`; but it seems that's the best we have to work with!)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, unlike floating point types, System.Decimal keeps track of the number of digits in the literal.  This is a feature of decimal.Parse(), whether executed by your code yourself or by the compiler when it parses a literal in your program.  You can recover this information, check out the code in my answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081854/determine-which-function-to-call-based-on-length-of-decimal/2081961#2081961).

Recovering the number of significant digits after you do math on the value strikes me as a long shot.  No idea if the operators preserve them, please let us know what you find out.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that info isn't preserved. Which makes sense -- I mean, considering something like `1M / 4M`, it should obviously come out to `0.25M` not `0.3M`. Anyway, I tackled the problem for a little bit and came up with something resembling a solution-in-the-making (complete with the very same bit twiddling I see you suggested in the linked answer!)... my code is very ugly, though. If you get a free minute later, I would definitely appreciate your thoughts on my update at the top of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution above falls out of bed quickly with values like 1200 where the number of significant digits is 2 but the function returns 4.  Perhaps there is a consistent manner to deal with such a situation i.e. check to make sure return value does not include trailing zeros in the whole number portion without a fractional part.