# Normalize a System.Decimal - strip trailing zeros

Tags: c#, format, decimal

I've got a pretty compact way of removing trailing zeros in decimal values but I'd prefer a way that doesn't involve string roundtripping as mine currently does. This is my current solution:

```
var value = 0.010m;
value = decimal.Parse(value.ToString("G29"));
Console.WriteLine(value); // prints 0.01 (not 0.010)
```

So it works, but do you have an even better way?

Also, as a secondary question is decimalValue.ToString() 100% conformant to xs:decimal?

Comment: - Of course I could repeatedly truncate and compare decimals until values are no longer equal. At least (0.010m == 0.01m)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683718/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-significant-figures-of-a-decimal

Comment: The best way to do it is with Jon's answer to the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298719/parse-decimal-and-filter-extra-0-on-the-right/4298787#4298787

Comment: Thanks Gabe & Thomas. This looks just like what I'm looking for, albeit quite a lot of code needed, but I'll take it. :-)

Comment: Oh, it requires BigInteger from .NET 4.0. That's a showstopper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove trailing zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525854/remove-trailing-zeros) - which has a great answer, too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7983330/709537

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a new draft idea:

```
public static class DecimalEx
{
    public static decimal Fix(this decimal value)
    {
        var x = value;
        var i = 28;
        while (i > 0)
        {
            var t = decimal.Round(x, i);
            if (t != x)
                return x;
            x = t;
            i--;
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

This might just do it. But it's very rough. Need to test and simplify it.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter how many SF the number is stored as but rather what happens when you output it.

Try

```
// The number of #'s is the number of decimal places you want to display
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0.###############");
// Prints 0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, `System.XmlConvert.ToString(decimal value)` is 100% conformant to xs:decimal.

This *should* be slightly faster.

```
public static decimal StripTrailingZeroes(this decimal value)
{
    return decimal.Parse(value.ToString("G29", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: @Bent - Sorry I can't help with the original problem - I did a half-attempt to figure out how `Decimal` works; it's poorly documented AND it looks like it could be tricky to modify the `int[4]` representation. I would make this an extension method and look at optimizing it later if it becomes a problem; chances are it isn't a big perf hit (sounds like premature optimization). I have edited my question with, what should be, the fastest string round-trip.

Comment: It's just this "splinter in my mind" issue: it shouldn't have to change representation to string to strip the trailing zeroes, so it nags me, but you are quite correct, it should be correct and that's the most important thing.

Comment: I know it would bug me too. Just look at some of my string manipulation answers - I hate doing stuff with strings.

Answer (score 0):

Casting to `double` and back to `decimal` should work.

```
decimal fixDecimal(decimal number) => (decimal)(double)number;
```

Though, there might be edge cases that I'm not aware of.