# Validate if a decimal has three positions

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a decimal field that I receive back in a controller in C# MVC. I need to know if it's value in decimal has no more than three positions.

So 0.00 is accepted as well as 0.01, but 0.001 would be denied.

Doing this:

```
if (discount > 1 || discount< (decimal) 0.01)
{
    // Log error
}
```

Only partially works since the 0.00 is denied. How could I do that?

Comment: See this question to count number of decimals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477689/find-number-of-decimal-places-in-decimal-value-regardless-of-culture You could find something of interest

Comment: @Vache That's solving a harder problem than this is.  It can work, but it's more work than you need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take the remainder when dividing by the decimal by `0.01`.  If it's zero, then there are no values after that decimal place, if there are some, then there are:

```
bool hasSomethingAfterSecondDecimalDigit = discount % 0.01m != 0m;
```

Note that this will work as expected for negative numbers as well.

Comment: Maths, maths, always the maths... I will try this out!

Answer (score 2):

Modulo is probably a more expensive operation than just plain old integer casting:

```
if((int)(discount*100) != discount*100) { /* more digits than wanted */ }
```

Both ways are probably just as fast in practice, and it's a matter of personal preference.

Another plain and simple approach:

```
if(Math.Round(discount, 2) != discount) { /* too precise */ }
```

Comment: This is actually going to be *more* expensive.  Calculating the remainder is going to be identical to performing the division.  In order to calculate the division you will have found the remainder; it's what's left after you do the division.  At a low level you generally have a `DIVMOD` function of some sort that calculates both; each operation either remainder or division, just takes the value it wants and discards the other.  Everything else you do, such as the multiplication, is extra effort spent.

Comment: You're referring to the previous version I corrected. It's only using multiplications now which are at FPU level certainly cheaper than divisions - I just doubt it'll be noticeable.

Comment: I agree it's not likely to be noticeable; I only commented because you brought it up.

Comment: Yeah well he has 3 valid solutions now, time to get nitpicky about the details  :P