# Get number of total decimal places in decimal (including non-significant ones)

Tags: c#, .net

If you run this code:

```
decimal d1 = 0m; 
decimal d2 = 0.0m;
decimal d3 = 0.0000m;

string str1 = d1.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string str2 = d2.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string str3 = d3.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You get :

```
str1: "0",
str2: "0.0",
str3: "0.0000"
```

Is there some way in code to get the number of decimal places (as would be output by decimal.ToString above) in the decimal variables ?

i.e. want to get:

```
d1: 0
d2: 1
d3: 4
```

(In case anyone is wondering why this is required, it is for some workaround code for a problem involving SSRS and Excel: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5c4fc104-5d69-409d-9a6e-a6354922729a/exporting-ssrs-report-to-excel-2007-excel-found-unreadable-content-in-file-xlsx)

**EDIT:**

Title has been changed. Sorry for the confusion, guys. In the underlying problem I'm trying to solve, the decimals are always 0 - hence the confusion.

Comment: Can you just call `ToString` and count number of digits after `.`?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - not a bad idea. I'll use it if there's nothing cleaner.

Comment: Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477689/find-number-of-decimal-places-in-decimal-value-regardless-of-culture

Comment: @V4Vendetta - thanks, burning_LEGION's answer there did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @V4Vendetta for pointing me to the other question.

This does the trick:

int count = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(yourDecimalHere)[3])[2];

(From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13493771/70140)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the trick doen't work: for the 0.000100m value the right answer is 3, not 6

Comment: I did not word my original question very well. I'm actually after the total number of decimal places (including non-significant ones). The trick does what I need. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

I think as this is what u need as MarcinJuraszek said

```
decimal d = 0.0000m;
int count = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).
            Substring(d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).
            IndexOf(".") + 1).Length;
```

Comment: if you don't specify CultureInfo it converts `dot` to `comma.`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko actually OP have not defined non-significant decimal places, thats why i thought this will do. OP should have posted example as yours

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal d3 = 0.0000m;
bool control = true;
string str = d3.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int zeroCount = str.Select((c, index) =>
        {
            if (index >  str.IndexOf('.') && c == '0' && control) return 1;

            control = false;
            return 0;
        }).Sum();
```

Comment: Sorry, but for 0.000100m the soultion(s) should return 3, not 5

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, you right.I didn't noticed `unsignificant part`.anyway I will change my answer though you are already write the correct method

Answer (score 1):

*Unsignificant digits* are those that are *between decimal separator* and *first non-zero digit* providing that the number has *zero integer part*, e.g.:

```
  0.000     - 3 unsignificant digits
  0.0001    - 3 
  0.000100  - 3 unsignificant digits (not 5!)
  0.12301   - 0
  0.1230    - 0
  0.0123    - 1
  1.0       - 0 unsignificant digits (not 1!)
  1.0000    - 0 unsignificant digits (not 3!)
 -0.0001    - 3
```

So, the solution can be

```
public static int UnsignificantDigits(Decimal value) {
  int result = 0;

  String St = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

  if (St.StartsWith("0.") || St.StartsWith("-0."))
    for (int i = St.IndexOf('.') + 1; i < St.Length && St[i] == '0'; ++i)
      result += 1;

  return result;
}

...

int count = UnsignificantDigits(0.000m); // <- returns 3
```