# SQL Server 'ROUND' vs C# 'Math.Round'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have following `SQL Server` statement, I want to convert this into `c#`. I know there is something called `Math.Round` in `C#`. I have tried but `C#` returns the same results c# returns an int back. For details please check the Test & results below:

**SQL SERVER**

```
Select ROUND(SUM(someValue) / 60,0)
```

**C#**

```
var alpha = Math.Round(someValue / 60, 0);
```

**Tests & Result**

```
select ROUND(150.75, 0)
-- Result = 151.00

var alpha = Math.Round(150.75, 0);
// Result = 151
```

Can anyone please suggest me why its not putting .00 in the end. In real values will there be any difference. I am looking ro replace SQL with C#.

Thanks

Comment: eve in SQL I am asking for 0 decimal place.

Comment: You must be doing ToString()?

Comment: I always thought 151 is the same number as 151.00

Comment: @Remus Rusanu please read my question properly. I am asking if it will differ with real time values.

Comment: Keep in mind that what you're seeing is not a number, but rather a string representation of a number.  SSMS or whatever you're using must automatically display decimal numbers with two decimal places while VS does not.  It doesn't change the value, just the representation.

Comment: Well, show an example with a real time value then :) As is everybody wil focus on the non-significant '.00' part

Comment: @RemusRusanu Thanks for your time focusing on 00. I got my answer :) I will update it with some real value soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [table on MSDN here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) Sql Server's `ROUND()` will return a decimal output for a decimal input.

The overloads of [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx) return either decimal or double, depending on the input type.

The reason why you aren't seeing `.00` therefore must be as a result of the formatting you are applying to the result.

(Speculative, but the default formatting on `string.Format` or `Debug.Writeline` may internally be using a technique [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477689/find-number-of-decimal-places-in-decimal-value-regardless-of-culture) to retrieve the number of decimal places and provide a default presentation), e.g.

```
int count = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(Math.Round(150.75M, 0))[3])[2];
```

Comment: thanks, will it make in difference with real time values. Because I am planning to replace a logic written in SQL with C#?

Comment: Depends what kind of precision you need - are you working with exact values or can you allow some error at high numbers of DP?

Comment: See this post for more info, might clarify which datatype you need (I'm thinking decimal) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when

Answer (score 1):

SQL is giving you the same datatype you put in - there is a precision setting for a decimal datatype in SQL and since you are specifying an number with 2dp, SQL returns a value with 2dp.

.NET doesn't share the same data types as SQL and is therefore returning a `double` (since you didn't specify the input as decimal)