# Remove decimal point from a decimal number

Tags: c#, decimal

I am trying to remove just the decimal point from a decimal number in C#.

For example:

- My decimal number is `2353.61` I want `235361` as the result.
- My decimal number is `196.06` I want `19606` as the result.

How can I do that?

Comment: multiply by 100...Will it always be two decimal places?

Answer (score 7):

I would simply get the number of decimals and multiply it by the correct power of 10. Probably not really a concern but this also would be faster and use less memory then casting it to a string splitting / recombining it, then casting it back to a double. This also works for any number of decimal places.

```
decimal d = 2353.61M;
int count = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(d)[3])[2];
d *= Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(10, count));
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477689/find-number-of-decimal-places-in-decimal-value-regardless-of-culture) answer to get the number of decimals.

Comment: FYI, 10 ^ count isn't what you think it is. Use Math.Pow instead. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you always want the printed value to include 2 digits for consistency, you can just multiple by 100 and truncate the result.

```
value = Math.Truncate(value * 100m);
```

This would provide the value you specified in both cases, but also provide a similar result for `2353.6` (-> `235360`).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this(if the dot is in an unknown place - otherwise it's a simple multipication):

```
string str = decNum.ToString().Replace(".",string.Empty);
decimal dec = decimal.Parse(str);
```

Comment: This solution is not culture-aware.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply it by ten? You could also use `Math.Round()`. That will round the number to it's nearest one.

Comment: multiplying by 10 will only move the decimal one place, it will have to be 100 for two places :)

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
    public decimal RemoveDecimalPoints(decimal d)
    {
        try
        {
            return d * Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(10, (double)BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(d)[3])[2]));
        }
        catch (OverflowException up)
        {
            // unable to convert double to decimal
            throw up; // haha
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be:

```
while((int)n != n) n *= 10;
```

Multiplying the number by 10 moves the decimal point 1 place to the right. You need to repeat this multiplication until there are no more numbers on the right side. To detect if there are more numbers on the right, you simply cast it to `int`, which drops the decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have taken decimal value as `1.09`, then we take the first index of value with first or default, then you can get value without decimals and without round off.

```
var dec = 1.09;
var op1 = Convert.ToDecimal(dec.ToString().Split('.').FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the value. Works in all cases, including negatives.

```
public int RemoveDecimalPoints(
    decimal value)
{
    var array = value.ToString().Split('.');
    var isPoint = array.Length == 2;
    var dec = array.FirstOrDefault() + (isPoint ? array.LastOrDefault() : "");
    return int.Parse(dec);
}
```