# How can I split a float (1,2) into 1 and 2 integers?

Tags: f#

I'm learning F# and have an assignment where I have to treat a float as a coordinate. For example float 2.3 would be treated as a coordinate (2.3) where x is 2 and y is 3.

How can I split the float to calculate with it?

I am trying to make a function to calculate the length of a vector:
let lenOfVec (1.2, 2.3) and using pythagoras' method to get the length of hypotenuse.

But I am already stuck at splitting up the float.

Hope some can help!

Comment: In other languages I use value retype to string .. then split by dot and in array I have first and second numbers

Comment: Ah okay, I thought there maybe was an easier way. But I'm going to do that as well then! Thank you for your fast answer.

Comment: Is it always fixed number of digits before and after the decimal point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having at your disposal libraries as rich as F#/.NET offer the task of splitting a float into two can be done with one short line of code:

```
let splitFloat n = n.ToString().Split('.') |> Array.map float
```

- library function [ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring) converts the argument `n` (supposedly `float`) to a `string`
- library function[Split('.')](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) applied to this string converts it into an `array` of two strings representing the first number before decimal dot and the second number after the dot
- finally this array of 2 `strings` is converted by applying library function [float](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.float%5B%5Et%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) to the each array element with the help of just another library function [Array.map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.map%5b't,'u%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d), producing the array of two sought floats

Being applied to a random float number the outlined chain of conversions looks like

123.456 --> "123.456" --> [|123;456|] --> [|123.0;456.0|]

Comment: Thanks, a really nice solution :-) Had to use Split(',') for it to work, otherwise it works great.

Comment: If you're writing code that will be used in many countries (some where numbers use `.` as a decimal point and some where they use `,`), then you need to look up the current decimal separator in `NumberFormatInfo`. First do `open System.Globalization`, then do `let sep = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator`. Now you can do `n.ToString().Split(sep, 1, StringSplitOptions.None)`. That's the safest way to write this code if you're intending it to be used in multiple cultures. (If you're just writing it for yourself, though, `Split(',')` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Stealing from a few other answers on here, something like this seems to work for a few examples:

```
open System

///Takes in a float and returns a tuple of the the two parts.
let split (n: float) = 
    let x = Math.Truncate(n)

    let bits = Decimal.GetBits(decimal n)
    let count = BitConverter.GetBytes(bits.[3]).[2]    
    let dec = n - x

    let y = dec * Math.Pow(10., float count)

    x, y
```

Examples:

- 2.3 -> (2.0, 3.0)
- 200.123 -> (200.0, 123.0)
- 5.23 -> (5.0, 23.0)

Getting the X is easy, as you can just truncate the decimal part.

Getting the Y took input from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872606/how-to-remove-decimal-point-from-a-decimal-number-in-c#24872677) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872606/how-to-remove-decimal-point-from-a-decimal-number-in-c).