# C# Convert currency to string, remove decimal point but keep decimals, prepend 0s to have fixed width

Tags: c#, fixed-width, currency-formatting

How do I convert money amount like this

```
38.50
```

, to fixed width like this

```
000003850
```

I dont want to add commas and decimal places as some suggested answers here are explaining how to do.  Neither do I want to remove decimals, I only want to remove decimal point.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Getting `3850` out of `38.50` should be as easy as multiplying by 100

Comment: Investigate [Numeric Format Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string.Format()` with custom format specifiers. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

```cs
double dollars = 38.50;   // your value
int temp = (int)(dollars * 100);   // multiplication to get an integer
string result = string.Format("{0:000000000}", temp);

// Output: 000003850
```

Comment: That works, too.  I just used my solution below but will accept your answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to @ReedCopsey at [How to remove decimal point from a decimal number in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872606/how-to-remove-decimal-point-from-a-decimal-number-in-c/24872677).

```
decimal amount = 38.50m;
int fixed_amount = (int)Math.Truncate(amount * 100);
Console.WriteLine(fixed_amount.ToString("D9"));
```

OUTPUT:

```
000003850
```