# Get number of digits in a decimal variable

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a winform program in visual studio 2015 to calculate Pi, but I'm having trouble trying to get the number of logical digits.

I need to make it so that:

```or-tag-here
public decimal pi = 3.15195647857832565; //random decimals
txtDigits.Text = //number of digits in pi variable and get rid of trailing decimal points
```

Comment: how many digits do you expect from, for ex, 1/3 ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you need to get the number of **logical** digits, IE stripping out trailing zeroes I suggest you use the accepted approach here:

[Find number of decimal places in decimal value regardless of culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477689/find-number-of-decimal-places-in-decimal-value-regardless-of-culture)

```
decimal argument = 123.456m;
int digitCount = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(argument)[3])[2];
```

I've used this approach in multiple projects and it works really nicely. Note that this is for finding the number of trailing decimal points (I assumed that's what you're after but it's not clear from your question).

Comment: seams to work fine, thanks

Comment: @user87073  `decimal argument = 1m/3;` returns 28. why not 29? or why not infinite? Improve your question.... And answer my comment posted ~48 mins ago...

Comment: @L.B Curious to know why this was downvoted? Seems odd to punish people for attempting to answer this question with high quality references just because OP didn't clarify exactly what he was after. I stated here that I *assumed* he was looking for trailing decimals. The method I've supplied here does exactly that. Or maybe you're just having a bad day?

Answer (score -2):

This will return the count of all the digits:

```
int i= 0;
foreach (char c in pi.ToString())
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            i++;
        }
}
```