# FluentAssertions to check number of characters after decimal point

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-assertions

Using `FluentAssertions`, is there any nice way to confirm the number of characters after a decimal point? I've been looking for the best way to do this but can't find much on it.

Comment: There's nothing built-in for this, but it seems like the first thing you'll need to do is [count the number of decimal digits in the number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477689/find-number-of-decimal-places-in-decimal-value-regardless-of-culture).

Comment: `var digits = numberString.Length - numberString.LastIndexOf(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator) - 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Or use `Should().MatchRegex()` on the string representation.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should use `Should().BeApproximately(args)` or `Should.BeInRange(args)`

Comment: Value and precision are different things.

Comment: Ah, you're completely right. I have no idea why I thought about this that way.