# C# remove all leading and trailing zeros from decimal string

Tags: c#

I have a decimal like like "-00.20300"

I want output like this

"-.203"

Any easy way to achieve this without removing the negative sign remove 0s and then reattaching negative sign?

Comment: Parse it to an *actual* decimal and use the number format you desire.

Comment: *without removing the negative sign remove 0s and then reattaching negative sign?* - why impose this restriction?

Comment: Just trying to see if there is more elegant way since I usually take the brute force approach

Comment: You can convince a decimal type to forget how many digits of precision it has with `value / 1.000000000000000000000000000000000m;`

Comment: Will the input string always contain a '.' or could "100" also be a possible input? What would you expect if the input is "0.0" - shall both zeroes be removed?

Comment: First you asked for "easy" (but shunned an actual "easy"), then you asked for "more elegant", which is a problem because it isn't really objective. I think you need to better define the parameters we need to work to, and the data we will work on..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the number of decimal digits you want in your output:

```
decimal val = -00.20300M;
string result = val.ToString(".###", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// result is "-.203"
```

If you don't know the number of decimal spots, you can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32837759/1043380) to calculate it (and include the `TrimEnd` because you're ignoring trailing zeros), then make the format from the count.

```
decimal val = -00.20300M;
var decimalCount = val.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .TrimEnd('0')
    .SkipWhile(c => c != '.')
    .Skip(1)
    .Count();

var format = "." + new string('#', decimalCount);
string result = val.ToString(format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// result is "-.203"
```

Answer (score 0):

Nyssa's comment is on the right track, and would be the right way to do things, but unfortunately none of the string formats built in to C# provide the behavior that you want.

Gunr's answer is correct, but only works when you know the number of useful digits.

Here is a general solution:

```
public static string TrimmedStringConversion(string numberString)
{
    const string minusSign = "-";
    var returnString = string.Empty;
    if (numberString.StartsWith(minusSign))
    {
        returnString = minusSign;
        numberString = numberString.Remove(0,1);
    }

    returnString += numberString.Trim('0');
    return returnString;
}
```

And the unit test/usage:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestStringConversion()
{
    var startingString = "-00.20300";
    var convertedString = TrimmedStringConversion(startingString);
    Assert.AreEqual("-.203", convertedString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to format the decimal value

```
decimal decValue = -00.20300M;
string result = decValue.ToString(".###");

Console.WriteLine(result);
```