# Given an input float, round another float so it has the same numbers after the decimal separator as the first

Tags: c#

The problem:

Given an input float (`value`), round another float (`anotherValue`) so it has the same significant figures as the first float (`value`).

---

What I have tried so far:

```
private static void Test()
{
    var value = 0.12345f;
    // ?? Strategy suggested by this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683718/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-significant-figures-of-a-decimal
    var significantFigures = decimal.GetBits((decimal)value);

    var anotherValue = 3.987654321;
    // ERROR: Argument 2: cannot convert from int[] to int
    var resultValue = (float) SetSignificantFigures((double)anotherValue, significantFigures.Length);

    // Desired result: resultValue = 3.988
}
```

This is the definition of `SetSignificantFigures`:

```
// Function suggested by this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374316/round-a-double-to-x-significant-figures
public static double SetSignificantFigures(double d, int digits)
{
    double scale = Math.Pow(10, Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(d))) + 1);
    return scale * Math.Round(d / scale, digits);
}
```

---

Blocking point: since `decimal.GetBits` returns `int[]`, I don't know how to proceed (or if it is the correct strategy).

Comment: What is the definition of *significant digits* ? Like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) ? The reason I am asking is that at first I thought you wanted the integer part of the number, but looks too easy for the efforts you are trying. But honestly so far from what I understood from the definition I brought - I still do not see a contradiction in saying that significant digits equals the integer part. Can someone give an example to show I am wrong ?

Comment: @Veverke Sorry if it is not the correct description in English (I thought the other posts suggested a similar definition?). What I mean is "how many digits are there after the floating point". Maybe the better way for me to explain it is with the same examples as in the post: the significant digits of 0.123 would be 3. The significant digits of 3.987654321 would be 9. Maybe I'll replace "digits" by "figures", as it seems to be the standard definition in English.

Comment: Convert the 1st float to string, culture invariant, then cut everything before "." with a regex or string. Split  and get the string's length. Round the new number to the lenght's digit

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. As for my remark above and an example of significant digits - following wikipedia's definition - it contains one, I just needed to go through. So you are not looking for what wikipedia defines as significant digits - rather you simply want the fractional part of the number.

Comment: I may be wrong, but the way floating-point numbers are stored, is there a way to identify *significant digits* unless we apply some sort of rounding?

Comment: @XavierPeña So the significant digits of 0.1230 would be 4? In that case, how do you tell that apart from 0.123? Or does the C# code representation not matter, and do you count the digits in `0.123f.ToString()` vs. `0.1230f.ToString()`? In that case, are you prepared to accept that calculations that should logically give `0.123f` may actually give something like `0.1299999f` or `0.12300001f` due to floating point inaccuracies, which would give a very much misleading number of significant digits?

Comment: @Veverke Thanks for pointing that out. Now I see what is wrong with my example. `// Desired result: resultValue = 3.987` sould be `// Desired result: resultValue = 3.988`. Sorry about that, I am going to correct it.

Comment: @hvd No need to differentiate, `0.1230` should be equivalent to `0.123`. Although if somehow the input is `0.1230f` (which in my case is not likely) I accept that it considers it as "4 figures after the floating point". `are you prepared to accept that calculations that should logically give 0.123f may actually give something like 0.1299999f`: no, this wouldn't fit my needs. In this case I would preffer the `string` strategy proposed by  K. Gkinis and Nitin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the number of digits why don't you parse the string equivalent of the number

```
        var value = 12.123f;
        var str = value.ToString().Split('.');
        int decimalCount = 0;
        if (str.Count() == 2)
        {
            decimalCount = str[1].Length; // this will give you 3.
        }
```

Comment: Ideally I would like the result to remain as close as possible to the "rounded" result, and not just "remove all remaining figures". With your example, `0.1239` set to only 3 figures would become `0.123` instead of `0.124`. But it is a shortcut I wouldn't have thought of, and I am using it if no other options come around. Thanks.

Comment: Now I see what is wrong with my example. `// Desired result: resultValue = 3.987` sould be `// Desired result: resultValue = 3.988`. Sorry about that, I am going to correct it.

Comment: In hindsight, I see that you are giving me an equivalent of how to get `significantFigures`. I can still use `SetSignificantFigures` if I want to round the result given those `significantFigures`. Marking it as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
var resultValue = SetSignificantDigits(anotherValue, significantDigits);
```

with this

```
var resultValue = SetSignificantDigits(anotherValue, significantDigits.Length);
```

Or try this

```
var significantDigits = value.ToString().Split('.')[1].Length; //perhaps replace '.' with ','
```

And in the `SetSignificantDigits`-Function replace this

```
return scale * Math.Round(d / scale, digits);
```

with this

```
return Math.Round(scale * (d / scale), digits);
```

Then it looks like this:

```
    var value = 0.12345f;
    var significantDigits = value.ToString().Split(',')[1].Length;
    var anotherValue = 3.987654321;
    var resultValue = SetSignificantDigits(anotherValue, significantDigits);

    public static double SetSignificantDigits(double d, int digits)
    {
        double scale = Math.Pow(10, Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(d))) + 1);
        return Math.Round(scale * (d / scale), digits);
    }
```

And the result is 3.98765

Comment: I tested this with `var value = 0.12345f;` and the result value was not correct.